# How do I resolve this "Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call `holder.getAdapterPosition()` to look it up later" error?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a music player to use on my smartphone and it has this error, I've searched for solutions and tested it in my code but nothing solves it or leaves me with even more errors.

I tested the app on my smartphone and it starts and it finds the files through the function of reading external storage, but it closes as soon as I click to play a song.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( MusicListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AudioModel songData = songsList.get(position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(songData.getTitle());

        if(MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex == position){
            holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }else {

        }

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //navigate to another acitivty

                MyMediaPlayer.getInstance().reset();
                MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("LIST",songsList);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

I already tried replacing with "holder.getAdapterPosition();" or adapt it to my code but I haven't found a way to make it work, I believe the method I'm using is correct but I still don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. For one, if something happens in onClick, you should add the code of that onClick.

Comment: I updated my question with the rest of the code.